# How to convert a SteamKit2.SteamApps+PICSTokensCallback into a meaningful message in C#

Tags: c#, steam

I have started coding in C# with SteamKit2.
Now the Problem is, that when I execute this Code :

```
Console.WriteLine("App {0} has product info => {1}", i, pics.ToString());
```

and formerly :

```
pics = await Apps.PICSGetProductInfo(app, null);
```

I cannot get the Product info ,but merely a Response in the form 
*"SteamKit2.AsyncJobMultiple`1+ResultSet[SteamKit2.SteamApps+PICSProductInfoCallback]"*
How would I convert it to something meaningful?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about this API, but I suspect the value you have is a call back to get the product info, not the product info itself.

Try something like:

```
    SteamClient steamClient = new SteamClient(); // you may already have this
    CallbackManager manager = new CallbackManager( steamClient );
    manager.Subscribe<SteamClient.PICSTockensCallback>(MyFunction);
```

then add a function like

```
    public void MyFunction( <figure out what params you need here> )
    {
        … code goes here
    }
```

Comment: I have tried that ,but there is no Option for it in vs 2017.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by no option for it.  I use it all the time in VS2017.  What 'type' is pics?

Comment: Well pics is of type             AsyncJobMultiple<SteamApps.PICSProductInfoCallback>.ResultSet pics;

Comment: if you type in var Info = pics?. what options do you get in intellisense?

Comment: Complete,Equals,Failed,GetHashCode,GetType,Results,ToString..nothing more.

Comment: Perhaps I would just have to Import the Invoke through a using directive ?

Comment: Looking here:  https://github.com/SteamRE/SteamKit/commit/68600222e42497099a754485845986717237c8e3  they seem to be calling (line 58) a subscribe function to other call backs and mention the PICSProductInfoCallback you are having trouble with, so maybe you need to subscribe rather than using it in the way we've been thinking.

Comment: Hmm, seems you are Right.I should write a method which could get subscribed via the Manager, but perhaps you could help me a Little doing that ?

Comment: See amended answer above

Comment: Though I have no Idea how to write that function since the API Always talks about "the given App ID", but I do not see an opportunity to set that somewhere..